# How to save a value of the same type as the dropdown list when making a textbox appear after selecting other from a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880699/make-a-textbox-appear-when-a-value-is-selected-from-a-dropdown-list-in-mvc) link to make a textbox appear when "other" value is selected from a dropdown list in MVC. It works smoothly. Now my problem is in saving the newly entered value from the user in a new field of the database and sending it back to the controller action. It is not working here is my view code the dropdown list and the textbox that appears below it and then my action and a picture of my sent variable. Help please I am confused.

**View**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="Other" class="form-group" >
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tbl_Category.OtherName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tbl_Category.OtherName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_Category.OtherName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tbl_Url myURL)
        {
            try
            {

                myURL.IsApproved = "P";
                myURL.UserId = objUserBs.GetALL().Where(x => x.UserEmail == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault().UserId;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    objBs.Insert(myURL);
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Created Successfully";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(objCatBs.GetALL(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");//taking data from tbl_Category for the dropdown list in the view, having the values of CategoryId displayed under the name CategoryName
                    ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(objUserBs.GetALL(), "UserId", "UserEmail");
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Create Failed " + e1.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

[image: other1]
[image: other2]

Comment: From the screenshots everything seems to be working as expected, what is the problem you are having exactly? If I have to take a guess is that you are having issues while saving the CategoryID (when Other CategoryID is zero and that is probably not allowed on the DB) not while implementing the feature you are after.

Comment: The modelstate is not turning out to be valid for some DB fields are assigned to null while they are deemed as required. I tried assigning them to an arbitrary value using "=" but the assignment didn't work.

Any Suggestions on how to assign a value to those fields?

Comment: You need to handle those situations based on your particular needs. In the case of other, what values are you supposed to save for CategoryID and CategoryDesc? Is there a need to save those fields at all. Based on your initial question the feature you are trying to implement is in perfect working order, if you are having another issue I will suggest you to start a new thread with the new problem you are having.